# Как называется такой компонент?

Tags: reactjs

Дизайнер подогнал такой дизайн для меню. Как он называется?
При выборе, к примеру, "Печати и штамы", должны показываться продукты соответствующей категории

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Есть такое в какой-нибудь ui библиотеке?

Comment: `Как он называется?` назвать такое можно "Фильтры"...

Comment: Если вы про сами кнопки, то скорее всего `chips`.